# Magento 2 - Mirasvit RMA data migration from M1 to M2

Tags: magento2, data-migration, core-config-data, mirasvit

We have migrated products, customers and orders details from M1 to M2 using https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html now we would like to migrate **RMA Mirasvit** data from M1 EE to M2 Commerce. Is this possible by using the data migration tool please advise?

Answer (score 1):

I've done the data migration of Aheadworks RMA from M1 to M2.
Extension provider will provide the data migration tool with their extension.

You can ask them regarding the same else you need to create a script to migrate the data of the 3rd party extension.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can use their direct migration script?

https://mirasvit.com/docs/module-rma/current/setup/migration

## Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Below are examples of scripts, which may be used for transferring data from Mirasvit RMA for Magento 1 to Mirasvit RMA for Magento 2.

To use scripts you need a help of PHP developer. Scripts may contain bugs and may not transfer all necessary data. So you may need to fit them for your needs. Migration service is not a part of our support service. If you need a help of our team, you'll need to buy a migration service.

Click on the names of scripts below to download:

[mirasvit_rma_m1_export.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rac1nghw972vocf/mirasvit_rma_m1_export.php?dl=1) - script for exporting RMA data to XML file.

[mirasvit_rma_m2_import.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5l4xhyjgr40hel/mirasvit_rma_m2_import.php?dl=1) - script for importing RMA data from XML file.